# Overwrite the default taxonomy view

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, panels

I want to overwrite the default taxonomy view. I am cloning the original one, but the view I get does not provide any item.

How can I achieve this? 
Also could I have two views, default and cloned enabled and visible through a panel?

It seems to be [a critical issue on an upgrade of the Views module[1](http://drupal.org/node/1949178).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't really comment on the no results problem.

However, the Taxonomy View renders as a page, so no you can't have both the original view and the cloned view enabled at the same time and expect them both to override taxonomy pages.

The only way to have both enabled is to set a different path for each view, which means one or both views would not override taxonomy pages at all.

If what you want to achieve is overriding taxonomy pages for terms of specific vocabularies, what I did was use the Disable Taxonomy Term Listing module to completely hide results of the normal taxonomy page, then replaced that content with taxonomy block views.  If this isn't what you are looking for then feel free to disregard this all ;-)

Comment: I found out, after quite a lot of hours spent, that you can have the original and the cloned view both having the same url. I actually wanted only a single term of the vocabulary to use another view. So I placed the 2 views in the same panel and it seemed to work! I can't give a thorough explanation why this happens! Thanks for the knowledgeable input :)

Comment: You could also just give that one view the direct path of the term you want to modify.  Instead of taxonomy/term/% + contextual filter.  Just remove the filter, and for path use taxonomy/term/<your tid here>.  That would avoid panels all together.

Answer (score 0):

Marking the answer here in case it save other people's time :)
Upgrade your views version to 3.7 and it should work!